# Not expected trend changing depending the timeframe we choose for multitimeframe trend

Tags: pine-script

i build a dashboard and want to display a trend for different timeframe on it such as 1,5,15,60,240 min.

On the next code we will just take the sma(close,20) to make it simple, the error is still there.

So i am comparing the sma(close,20) with the same expression lagging with 5 bars to get the trend.
I need to do it 5 times with security to get the trend of the 5 timeframes.

But when you copy past my code in tradingview and switch between timeframes ( 1 min 1h 4h ... ) there are some switch on the trend and this is not expected.. Because i want to see the same result from what ever timeframe i am looking the chart.

If there is some switch between them there is no point to construct this type of dashboard since it is not reliable.

So i have thoutgh about it. And maybe we can fix this issue if we go to the lowest timeframe ( 1min) and construct "custom candle 1,5,15,60,240 min" and make all calculation with the close of theses custom candle. But this is fancy stuff and it still does not fix the main issue, because the main purpose is to see that type of result on all the chart and not only on chart 1min.

Do i missing something about pinescript? How would you do what i am trying to achieve ?
Thanks for your help!

Here is the code :

```
//@version=4
strategy("Not working Dashboard", overlay=true,initial_capital= 100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.04)

//********************** TITLE
i_offsetLabel = 15
offset = i_offsetLabel * ( time - time[1])
splitter = "---------------------------------------------------------------------"
nl = "\n"
title = "Not working Dashboard" 

string dynamicText = title + nl
var label id = na
label.delete(id)        // Delete Last label
id := label.new(x=time+offset,y = high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text = dynamicText)

// Lets make a cppm dashboard with same components
yReadable0=input(true,title="-------------------CHOOSE DISPLAY-------------------")

i_showBooleanCondition        = input(true, "Show BooleanCondition")

ColorCallsTitle = splitter + nl+ "Color Changing calls" +nl +nl

ssrc1=input(1,title="Source 1",minval=1, step=1)
ssrc2=input(5,title="Source 2",minval=1, step=1)
ssrc3=input(15,title="Source 3",minval=1, step=1)
ssrc4=input(60,title="Source 4",minval=1, step=1)
ssrc5=input(240,title="Source 5",minval=1, step=1)

//------------
up = ""
dn = ""
//Luda added flat emoji
flt = "⛔️"
string txt = na

pssrc1 = tostring(ssrc1)
pssrc2 = tostring(ssrc2)
pssrc3 = tostring(ssrc3)
pssrc4 = tostring(ssrc4)
pssrc5 = tostring(ssrc5)

X1src = close

XCustomResolution1= "1"
XCustomResolution2= "5"
XCustomResolution3= "15"
XCustomResolution4= "60"
XCustomResolution5= "240"

r=sma(close,20)
r2=r[5]
f_security(_sym, _res, _src, _rep) => security(_sym, _res, _src[not _rep and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_rep or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
X1 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution1,r,false)
X2 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution2,r,false)
X3 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution3,r,false)
X4 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution4,r,false)
X5 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution5,r,false)

X11 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution1,r2,false)
X22 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution2,r2,false)
X33 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution3,r2,false)
X44 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution4,r2,false)
X55 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid,XCustomResolution5,r2,false)

// ploting
plot(X1,title="sma1",color=color.green)
plot(X2,title="sma2",color=color.green)
plot(X3,title="sma3",color=color.green)
plot(X4,title="sma4",color=color.green)
plot(X5,title="sma5",color=color.green)

plot(X11,title="lag1",color=color.white)
plot(X22,title="lag2",color=color.white)
plot(X33,title="lag3",color=color.white)
plot(X44,title="lag4",color=color.white)
plot(X55,title="lag5",color=color.white)

//trend
Xsym1 =X1 > X11 ? up : X1 < X11 ? dn : flt
Xsym2 =X2 > X22 ? up : X2 < X22 ? dn : flt
Xsym3 =X3 > X33 ? up : X3 < X33 ? dn : flt
Xsym4 =X4 > X44 ? up : X4 < X44 ? dn : flt
Xsym5 =X5 > X55 ? up : X5 < X55 ? dn : flt

txt :=  " | " + pssrc1 +" : " + Xsym1 + " | " + pssrc2 +" : " + Xsym2 + " | " + pssrc3 +" : " + Xsym3 + " | " + pssrc4 +" : " + Xsym4 + " | " + pssrc5 +" : " + Xsym5 +"\n"+"\n"  
ColorChang = i_showBooleanCondition ? ColorCallsTitle + "Trend: " + nl + txt + nl : na

//dynamicText := dynamicText + stats + moms + vols + sigs
dynamicText := ColorChang
label.set_text(id, text=dynamicText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the security function to access other timeframes, note that your chart's resolution should be equal or lower to the lowest timeframe of the security call, calling lower-then-chart timeframes would lead to inconsistent results.

More information and an example could be found here:
[Is it possible to use security() on lower intervals than the chart’s current interval](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-security-on-lower-intervals-than-the-charts-current-interval)